# Is it more correct to use the minor and major foot groups in the IPA than commas and periods?

Tags: phonetics, ipa, transcription, phrases

I transcribed some phrases from TV. This is casual American connected speech:

[image]

As you can notice I'm using the `|` and `||` symbols instead of the commas and periods. Also, I do not show the question mark, exclamation mark, etc.. in the IPA as they have a different meaning in the phonetic transcription as far as I know.

[image]

Is it okay how I'm transcribing them? or should I revert back on using the commas and periods. Is it just a matter of preference?

Comment: Hi Zoltan. Have you ever thought about attending the UCL (University College London) [Summer Course in English Phonetics](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/pals/study/continuing-professional-development/summer-course-english-phonetics-vscep-2022)? It is RP based, but that doesn't matter too much. You can attend online or in person. You'd meet some great phoneticians, and be lectured by some. You'd meet some great people and could also ask all of these questions and get responses from genuine experts!